# How to calculate daily standard deviation from data collected hourly in R?

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I calculated daily means from hourly data for all four variables in the dataset without any issues using the `xts` function `daily.apply(df.xts, FUN=mean)`. By doing that I get daily averages of each of my variables. However, I am not being able to do the same for the standard deviation. When using `daily.apply(df.xts, FUN=sd)` I just get the index (time stamps) and only one column with values as an output. What am I missing? Similar issue for `var`.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See issue's [124](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/124) and [128](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/124) on github to see the reasoning why.

Solution (for now?), use an extra package called matrixStats. The code below will return the standard deviation per column of an xts object.

```
apply.daily(df.xts, matrixStats::colSds)
```